# How to insert php in html?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Updated- Added the insert code to save.php, but clicking on Save, no action is happening. Fields values are not getting inserted to db and also I am not getting the alert. Please advice.

I am trying to insert few user inputs to my mysql database using Ajax. Here is my html page:

```
<form id="form1" action="#" method="post">
            <table style="padding-top: 25px;">
                <tr style="height: 40px;">
                    <td style="text-align:right;">field1:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="field1" required/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 40px;">
                    <td style="text-align:right;">field2:</td>
                    <td style="width: 286px;"><input type="text" id="field2"/>    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 40px;">
                    <td style="text-align:right;">Field3</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="field3"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td style="padding-top: 20px;">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" id="Save"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
           </table>
</form>
```

Here is my Ajax:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {          
            $('#Save').click(function() {   
                var field1 = $('#field1').val();
                var field2 = $('#field2').val();
                var field3 = $('#field3').val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    async: false,        
                    url: 'save.php',
                    data: {
                            'saverecord': 1,
                            'field1':field1, 
                            'field2':field2, 
                            'field3':field3,
                    success: function(data) 
                    {
                        if(data==0){
                                $('#field1').val('');
                                $('#field2').val('');
                                $('#field3').val('');       
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

In my save.php file, I am trying to connect to my mysql database like this:

```
<?php
 $cn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");    
 if($cn) 
 {
    mysql_select_db('databasename', $cn);
 }
 if(isset($_POST['saverecord']))
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES
      ('{$_POST['field1']}','{$_POST['field2']}','{$_POST['field3']}')");
        alert("Inserted successfully");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Please let me know how I can insert the above mentioned 3 field values into my table using Ajax and html? Thank you so much.

Comment: Please avoid using the _deprecated_ mysql functions and move to either `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: I'm sure you got the answer by now `;-)`

Comment: Katie reply here so we can talk? _related to your problem ofcourse_. Did you make the required changes to your query as well?

Answer (score 1):

Put the insert in save.php, after the connection code. Your PHP code has to be in a .php file, or your server must be configured to parse .htm/.html files as PHP code. Otherwise, it is not processed and is sent to the browser as HTML, PHP code and all, and the browser sees `<?php ... ?>` as simply a weird HTML tag.

Also, please [don't use `mysql_*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1); the `mysql_*` functions are outdated, [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), and insecure. Use [`MySQLi`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.

On that note, you are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). You *must* use prepared statements or at least properly escape data before adding it to a SQL query or you *will* get hacked.

Comment: Now this is the answer that makes some sense `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

The query should be like :

```
"INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES ('".$_POST['field1']."','".$_POST['field2']."','".$_POST['field3']."')"
```

**This must be in a .php file that your ajax is pointing i.e, save.php**

Also please avoid using the deprecated mysql functions and move to either mysqli

Comment: _I am not sure where or how to add the insert queries in html. I tried adding like below in my html page_ Are you sure this would help?

Comment: I understand that you have the best of intentions to help out, but the way he writes his query technically work. I would suggest that you eloborate your answer so that he can solve the issue he has. And, when you suggest using mysqli_* or PDO (which you do and should do) then write your examples using prepared statements accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

insert Query will be place in your save.php file

For your connection

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 


    "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES
          ('".$_POST['field1']."','".$_POST['field2']."','".$_POST['field3']."')"
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Have a look at prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be in the `save.php` file that you post to. Basically combine the last 2 code blocks into `save.php`.